# Word to describe the way cattle and buffalo consume fodder?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you describe the the way cattle buffalo chew ("re-chewing", specifically) their food? There is a specific aspect of their *food eating habit* which is often related to how people work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sought after word is **[Ruminate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ruminate)** - which means:

> 1. To think deeply about something (wrt behavior of human beings), or
> 2. To chew the cud (wrt a ruminant).

Comment: @Rathony. Of course that's what it means -- chewing cud -- that's what they do, and it's exactly what was asked for. What edit would you suggest to make the question clearer, considering the OP didn't know the term at the time?

Comment: This describes a bovine's digestive system, *not* how they **grind** their food.

Comment: The grinding of the food is absolutely essential to what it means to be a ruminant.  While we have some flat molars, too, there's no way we could eat grass; a human could never train their body to, there's no way to do it.  Ruminants are eating an extremely low-nutrition diet, which they have to approach in a very specific, high-effort form of digestion – which **_includes_** the teeth and act of chewing; the fact that ruminants hork stuff up and re-chew it only makes their teeth and manner of chewing _more_ important and integral to the uniqueness of the process.  So isn't **ruminate** valid?

Comment: Furthermore, @displayName specifically said they _knew_ a word for _bovine chewing_ — at this point, Occam's Razor clearly dictates that _if_ displayName were some bovine specialist and had once known a truly exotic word for their chewing in veterinary school, would they _realllly_ have asked for it _here_?  Nah, they'd know it professionally or own the textbook.  Match the sophistication of the answer (I'm betting "**ruminate**" is at least the word they remembered) to the sophistication of the question (nothing harder than, say, "**bovine**").

Comment: All you had to do was add a link, and explain its meaning, and Bingo! It was perfect. We discourage one word answers on EL&U for obvious reasons.

Comment: @davidmacCaryrichter I see "Occam's Razor" in your comments. I think you're getting addicted to that phrase. ;)

Answer (score 4):

**[Ruminate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ruminate)** is the word that describes the manner of eating of cows, buffaloes and other animals. The animals that use this method are called ruminants.

> Rumination Syndrome — a chronic condition characterized by effortless regurgitation of most meals following consumption.

Taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumination_syndrome).

In the dictionary it's given as the first meaning. The "simple meaning" is to think profoundly.

Comment: Can you please supply a link to the dictionary you used?

Comment: "Mercyism", wooooww... my brain just fell off its stool trying to make sense of that one!

Comment: Would you believe me if I told you that I used the same source. I used the wikipedia reference here because I thought it would be clearer. But the dictionary mentioned is Merriam-Webster.

Comment: Hmm... Didnt know that.

Comment: You also **must** add a citation for each quote **in plain text** which will remain after all links have been removed (by a faulty API consumer, for example). There are [rules](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and [discussion of the rules](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4973/what-to-do-about-missing-source-attributions) and [worked examples following the rules](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/new-attribution-rules/5196#5196).

Comment: @AndrewLeach — THANK YOU for specifically spelling-out that reminder for the inexperienced.  I don't think I've trespassed on that yet, but I'll always take a tip to neaten things up :)  cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Once it's in their mouth (*again* or not*), they **grind** it with their molars.

> Cow's teeth are different from ours. On the top front, cows have a tough pad of skin instead of teeth. They have 8 incisors on the bottom front and 6 strong molars on the top and bottom of each side to **grind** their food. Cows have a total of 32 teeth. –[moomilk.com](http://www.moomilk.com/faq/1-cow-faqs/12-do-cows-have-special-teeth-for-eating-grass)

---

> *[Ruminants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruminant) are mammals that are able to acquire nutrients from plant-based food by fermenting it in a specialized stomach prior to digestion, principally through microbial actions. The process typically requires the fermented ingesta (known as cud) to be regurgitated and chewed again. **The process of rechewing the cud to further break down plant matter and stimulate digestion is called rumination**. The word "ruminant" comes from the Latin *ruminare*, which means "to chew over again". –Wiki

Comment: "Grind" is in bold, because the OP originally asked for a way to describe their 'chewing' as opposed to the whole digestive process.

Comment: Dude, chewing IS the digestive process, Step #1.    That's a non-starter.  See my two other comments to get a better idea of why the chewing isn't simple and easy — you're taking for granted that chewing is simple, big deal.  Nah, the _way_ and the _why_ and all the science of what's going into it means the chewing – and **don't forget Occam's Razor** – is really important, and "ruminate" is 100% the answer.

Comment: Comments like those would make me question the sobriety of their poster.

Comment: I'm a teacher, and you've made your point twice and not substantiated it with anything.  Go search on it; go rebut the Occam's Razor point; try anything other than the same thing.....which, incidentally is what they say is a definition of addiction (I didn't come up with it).  **Also, I don't drink.**  _Ad hominem_ is inappropriate, and comes off as flailing.

Comment: @davidmacCaryrichter Hi, David. The question has been edited several times. You don't need to use such words as "dude", "Nah", "effing stupidest", "goddamned", "sucks"...

Comment: Oooh, also you'll see that @displayName _asked_ the question, and _then_ confirmed "**ruminate**" as the answer, wow, _3 hours ago_, so at least 2 and a half hours _before_ you posted your first gripe on this question.  Teachable moment: make sure you're still arguing in an argument that hasn't been settled, is all.  Lesson for me too!!

Comment: @Rathony — thank you, I won't do it again, still getting the feel of the place versus other forum-y sites!  Avoiding it in the future everywhere here will be easy, thx.  A failed attempt to sound casual and lighthearted and teasing, is all.  I think I just wanted to talk about unicorns ;) cheers & gnight

Comment: @davidmacCaryrichter - All I've attempted to do, is add an answer with as much relevant information as possible. Answers are to stand alone, by themselves, on SE. The OP was kind enough to hit us up with a response, but it was a one liner-link. This answer is better, if I may say so, and had I not even typed anything out myself, it is my custom to make answers like that CWs, but the effort level of my answer here, IMO, was beyond that (and worthy of my fake internet points).

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the edits to the question have lessened it's usefulness. Associating "cow eating" with "ruminating" is potentially useful. I edited it to make it consistent, but though it lost something in the process. It is now unrecogniziable. I propose it gets rolled back to the OP's original statement.

Comment: @Mazura, I really don't quite get what you're missing here: digestion INCLUDES chewing — think about it: _**every single individual element**_ of your entire food-eating tract _**can be individually removed**_ and you can still eat and still be said to digest.  No stomach?  We can do that.  No esophagus?  Easy-peasy.  Everything from your lips to your butthole is capable of being gone-without and you would _**still**_ be said to digest.  (Okay, the only thing you really really _can't_ lose is your entire small intestine).  So you _**arbitrarily**_ chose to exclude chewing from digestion.

Comment: "Grinding" doesn't mean a thing — it's as specific as calling all squares rectangles – because hey, all squares are!  But sometimes it matters to be more specific and say "square".  Also, it's completely _obvious_ that the OP was _asking_ for a word they already knew that related to what turned out to be _ruminants_ — that was the word they wanted, done case-closed.  My disagreement was with your assumption that the one definition you found was correct in _over_-simplifying the process of ruminating and the role of chewing.  In short, I thought both of your contributions were close, but missed

Comment: [masticate](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/masticate) : chew (food); to bite and grind with the teeth “The cows were masticating the grass” @davidmacCaryrichter (that search was neither loaded with "cow" nor "grind", I simply googled *masticate*)

Comment: @Mazura: Thanks for your answer and suggested corrections. I have updated the Q as well as my A to more specifically reflect what I was looking for.

Comment: @Mazura, masticating refers to things that you do too.  displayName was asking for something specific to _a particular group_ of farm animals.  Insofar as you are not a farm animal, **masticate** is an ill-fitting answer.  Move on, is all – I mean, judging by your waywayway bigger reputation score or whatever it's called, you've got a heck of a lot of good advice to give, eh :)  peace!  sorry to've come off like such a jerk

Answer (score 2):

There's also **munch**

Eat (something) steadily and often audibly

Source: Oxford Dictionary of English

Comment: I'd suggest that this would be interpreted to connote something as casual and lighthearted as "snacking"... **munching/snacking** seem like something one does at leisure.  **Ruminants ruminate** because they don't have a choice but to chew and spit it up and chew and spit it up, because they're eating nutritionally-useless crap like grass.  Those animals would die like total sissies if they didn't do everything they can to keep the organisms that grow in their digestive tract alive and healthy, so they _always_ have (the same type of) food in there so the bacteria never go hungry.

Answer (score 1):

Cattle do have a habit of chewing partially digested food.  The common name for the mass of food being chewed for a second time is *cud*.

The phrase "chewing their cud" has gained several metaphoric senses: taking time to ponder and consider before completing some action and engaging in smalltalk are two that I easily recognize.

http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/91100.html
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/chew-the-cud

In the context of how people work, "chewing their cud" could refer either to *slacking and lollygagging* or to *beginning a task again before it is finished*.